# How to return the date when a field changed in a history table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using a MS SQL Server 2012 Database.
I'm querying a customer history table which logs whenever a customer changes any of their details. They might change their name, telephone number, address etc.

A new row is inserted with a time & date stamp whenever any of the customer details fields changes, including every field in the entire customer record, whether that field was changed or not.

I'm only interested in the date that the customer's postcode changed, I want to exclude any other type of change.

I've tried a few different types of query with no success, functions like LAG or QUALIFY that I've read about being used to do this in other variants of SQL don't seem to exist in SQL Server.

```
SELECT CH.CustomerID,
       MAX(CH.UpdateDate) AS LastAddressUpdate
  FROM CustomerHistory CH
 WHERE CH.Postcode NOT IN ...
```

I want the customer ID and the most recent date that the postcode changed

Comment: I think a bit of sample data, or at least table schema would be very helpfull here for us to be able to help you better

Comment: Do you want only the last date that the postcode changed, or all rows in history where the postcode changed ?

Comment: Just the most recent date in the history that the postcode changed. Gordon's answer below has worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select customerid, max(updatedate)
from (select ch.*, lag(postcode) over (partition by customerid order by updatedate) as prev_postcode
      from customerhistory ch
     ) ch
where prev_postcode <> postcode
group by customerid;
```

Note:  This assumes that `postcode` is not `null`.  The query can be modified to take this into account if that is possible.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. LAG doesn't change to blue or pink in SSMS so I had assumed it didn't exist!

Comment: As of SSMS 18.3.1, LAG now changes to pink. Progress!